# Using strip to print a list

Tags: python

The strip command does not work on a list that contains other lists.
E.g. `[ “ one”,”two “,[ “four”,”five”]]`
I want to print out the words without the [].

Is there a way to get around this?

It turns out I was using append to build a list from other lists.
I have now used the extend command instead to build the list which dispenses with the [] brackets, so printing is now straightforward. The extend command was not one I was familiar with before.

Comment: Can you be more clear on the output you want for that scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you just want to have a string representation without square brackets, you can do this:

```
l = [..., [...]]
s =str(l).replace("[", ""). replace("]", "")
print(s)
```

Mind that this can be misleading in many cases, because a list element that is a list of list looks like multiple string-type list elements. So you might want to reconsider why you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[` and `]` are forming a list, in your example a nested list.
You could use a recursive function to print it all out:

```
lst = [' one', 'two ', ['four', 'five']]

def recursive_print(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            recursive_print(item)
        else:
            print(item.strip())

recursive_print(lst)
```

This yields

```
one
two
four
five
```

---

If you want to collect the stripped words, you could use

```
def recursive_yield(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from recursive_yield(item)
        else:
            yield item.strip()

flattened = [word for word in recursive_yield(lst)]
print(flattened)
```

Which would yield

```
['one', 'two', 'four', 'five']
```

Both functions will work for arbitrarily nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[ "one","two",[ "four","five"]]
for i in l:
    if(isinstance(i,list)):
        for j in i:
            print(j,end=' ');#sep by spaces
    else:
        print(i,end=' ');
```

output:

one two four five

Comment: This looks promising,thank you. I was hoping for something simpler but this will do the job.